# Allow convert-to-comment without confirmation and even if there are comments

Tags: script, comments, flags

This userscript allows moderators to use the "convert to comment" button even if the answer has comments. It also removes the annoying `confirm()` prompt when converting an answer to a comment.

You can [find the source on GitHub](https://github.com/ThiefMaster/SO-UserScripts) (feel free to fork, improve and send a pull request) or just [install it right away](https://github.com/ThiefMaster/SO-UserScripts/raw/master/StackOverflow_ConvertToComment.user.js).

#### ChangeLog:

- 1.0: Initial release
- 1.1: Remove everything but the `confirm()` to reflect recent changes made by SE